# Prove that $(1+2\cos\frac{2x}{3})\sin\frac{x}{3}=\sin x$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: trigonometry

I got the answer for x in C not IR

> Prove that for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ 
>   $$(1+2\cos\dfrac{2x}{3})\sin\dfrac{x}{3}=\sin x$$

Comment: Have a look at [this thread on meta Math.SE about how to ask a good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).  I think you are asking about $x \in \mathbb{R}$ as opposed to $x \in \mathbb{C}$, but if you "got the answer" for complex $x$, this includes real numbers $x$ as a special case.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**
use
$$2\cos (a)\sin (b)=$$
$$\sin (a+b)-\sin (a-b) $$

with $a=2x/3$ and $b=x/3$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- $$1+\cos\left(\frac{2x}{3}\right) =  2\cos^2\left(\frac{x}{3}\right) \implies 1+2\cos\left(\frac{2x}{3}\right) = \cos\left(\frac{2x}{3}\right) + 2\cos^2\left(\frac{x}{3}\right).$$
- $$2\cos\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{2x}{3}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

$1+2\cos2x=1+2(1-2\sin^2x)=? $

Now $\dfrac{\sin3x}{\sin x}=? $